# Index was outside the bounds of the array error after a long idle time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have class like this that reads the data from database once and keeps it in memory.

```
public class PlanetService
{
    private List<Planet> planets = new List<Planet>();

    public List<Planet> FindAll()
    {
        if (!planets.Any())
        {
            planets.AddRange(GetAllPlanetsFromDataBase());
        }

        return planets;
    }

    public List<Planet> FindByName(string name)
    {
        if (!planets.Any())
        {
            planets.AddRange(GetAllPlanetsFromDataBase());
        }

        return planets.Where(x => x.Name == name).ToList();
    }
}

public class Planet
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Lookup
{
    public Lookup(string value, string label)
    {
        Value = value;
        Label = label;
    }
    
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

This is being used as follows

```
var lookupList = planetService.FindAll().Select(x => new Lookup(x.Id.ToString(), x.Name)).ToList();
```

This works as expected initially. But every now and then, usually after a long idle time, the following error occurs

> [IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the
> array.]    System.Collections.Generic.Enumerator.MoveNext()
> System.Linq.WhereSelectListIterator'2.MoveNext()
> System.Collections.Generic.List'1..ctor(IEnumerable'1 collection)
> System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable'1 source)

There is always planets in the database. And even if not it should return an empty Lookup list and shouldn't be throwing an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, right?

Once this error occurs, subsequent page refreshes keeps showing this error and won't go away for sometime.

Since other database calls are working I assume this is not connection related.

This happens in production only, I am unable to recreate the issue in the dev environment yet.

Comment: Can you show the code for `GetAllPlanetsFromDataBase()`?

Comment: @CharlesHan It just returns a list of planets (`IEnumerable<Planets>`) from database using sqlkata. `var db = new QueryFactory(dataAccess.GetConnection(), this.compiler); var query = db.Query("Planets").Select("Id", "Name").OrderBy("Ordinal"); return query.Get<Planet>();`

Comment: Log the result from GetAllPlanetsFromDataBase() and see if any data is returned when the error occurs. Since you are using a third-party library, log a support ticket with them.

Answer (score 0):

This exception in my experience tends to come when you try to Serialize massive amounts of data, usually massive single columns from the database.

Are any of the columns you're retrieving from the database containing abnormally large amounts of data?

We had a REST API which had this same exception where the cause was a column in the DB which had grown to GB's in size due to a self referencing bug.

Comment: The table is quite small. The columns are Id(uniqueidentifier, not null), Name(varchar(255), not null), Ordinal(int, not null)